# https needed for certain feature in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There's a recent update in Google Chrome's security in which they don't allow using the geolocation and accessing webcam when the site is not 'https'.

Is there a way to disable this for local IP addresses? We're only using it in out intranet so there's no way to put https in it.

Hope somebody can help me

Thanks

Comment: DNS Rebinding attacks can then allow attackers to set something up to bounce off an internal IP and send the data out. That is one reason this isn't allowed. This deprecation is because these APIs are now considered *Powerful Features* which should only be accessed via HTTPS. For more information on the deprecation the [Chromium Wiki](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) has an entry for what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

It only works on localhost, but not on the internal network.

The best I can suggest is to install a local page on each user's localhost. The page, when loaded, would store the user's location, record it in memory, then call an endpoint on your local network to transmit the data.